# How to type hint a type that implements a `__call__` method?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm experimenting with [PEP 0484 type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in Python 2.7. For most cases, it is pretty straightforward, but I stumble over the following function. I tried:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Callable, Union, Dict

T = TypeVar('T')

def ensure_cls(cls):
    # type: (Type[T]) -> Callable[[Union[T, Dict]], T]
    """
    If the argument is an instance of cls, pass, else try constructing.
    """

    def converter(val):
        # type: (Union[T, Dict]) -> T
        if isinstance(val, cls):
            return val
        else:
            return cls(**val)  # 'cls' is not callable

    return converter
```

PyCharm (2017.1.2) complains about 'cls' not being callable. This may be a false positive of the PyCharm inspections, but, on the other hand, PyCharm does have a point: not all types are callable.

Maybe there is a better way to type hint this function and specify that cls is actually a callable type?

What would be the recommended way to type hint above function?

Comment: A use case of above function you find here: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/12#issuecomment-247808132

Comment: I have the same question. However, IMO this question targets classes with specific `__init__` methods, which are called when the type gets called, and not certain classes with `__call__`, as this gets called when a class *instance* gets called.